# VS Code doesn't open from Git Bash terminal (but only in some conda environments)

Tags: visual-studio-code, conda, git-bash, environment

I am used to calling the shortcut 'code' to open VS Code from the Git Bash terminal, either in a specific folder or to open a file. This works fine in my default environment with common packages. But it doesn't work in the base environment and throws this error:

```
$ code .
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:990
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Library\c\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\cli.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:987:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:832:27)
    at c._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:13343)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

(Notice the filepath for cli.js references my C directory twice as if it tried to look into ProgramData and Program Files, which are not nested directories. The correct path is c\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\cli.js)

And it throws this other error when I try it in a different environment (called wisdem-env) I installed from a [public repo](https://github.com/WISDEM/WISDEM/tree/develop), then crashes my terminal

[terminal error opening VS code in wisdem-env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEUz5.png)

If I open VS Code from the normal Windows Start menu, I can load and work in any of the above environments just fine. But having the shortcut from the terminal makes my workflow better. I originally installed VS Code with default settings and haven't changed anything manually in my PATH. What do I need to set up to use this shortcut from any environment?

I already tried re-installing the wisdem-env without any luck. I tested the 'code' shortcut in all environments using the Anaconda Prompt terminal and it works fine there, but I prefer Git Bash.

**Edit: pasting contents of VSCode Help: About below**

Version: 1.80.2 (user setup)

Commit: 2ccd690cbff1569e4a83d7c43d45101f817401dc

Date: 2023-07-27T20:40:28.909Z

Electron: 22.3.14

ElectronBuildId: 22695494

Chromium: 108.0.5359.215

Node.js: 16.17.1

V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0

OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19044

Comment: Welcome! 1) Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. 2) from where did you install VS Code? 3) is this related? https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/158543

Comment: @starball added the contents of Help: About to the question. I installed VS Code from their website (https://code.visualstudio.com/Download). I uninstalled and re-installed after the issue started to see if my VS Code was just outdated and that didn't address it either. on 3) that's almost the same error I get, but in my case the cli.js path referenced in the error message is incorrect too